# Django: Page not found (404) when posting form data

Tags: django, forms, redirect, django-views

I am trying to create a form to submit a blog post on an author detail page, so that the blog post will automatically use the current author as its "blog_author" foreign key. I'm aware that this approach isn't "secure" - it's a project site, and I'm trying to learn a new design pattern.
The Django docs recommended using 1 parent view and 2 subviews to handle get and post respectively (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/mixins/).

The page renders fine with the get, but the post gives me an error reading "Page not found (404) - no blog post found matching the query." The exception is raised by my parent view (blog.views.AuthorDetail), but there is no traceback.

Edit: Form should have been a ModelForm from the beginning

Here are my views:

```
class BlogAuthorDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = BlogAuthor

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = BlogSubmitForm()
        return context

class BlogSubmit(SingleObjectMixin, FormView):
    template_name = 'blogauthor_detail.html'
    form_class = BlogSubmitForm
    model = BlogPost
    
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return HttpResponseForbidden()
        self.object = self.get_object()
        #Should I be overriding form_valid() to use the line above? Not sure if I'm doing my data 
        #handling in the right place
        return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        blogpost = form.save(commit=False)
        blogpost.blog_author = self.object
        blogpost.save()
        return redirect('blog_author-detail', pk=self.object.id)
        
class AuthorDetail(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        view = BlogAuthorDetailView.as_view()
        return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        view = BlogSubmit.as_view()
        return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

URLs:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('blogs/', views.BlogPostListView.as_view(), name='blogs'),
    path('blog/<int:pk>', views.BlogPostDetailView.as_view(), name='blogpost-detail'),
    path('bloggers/', views.BlogAuthorListView.as_view(), name='bloggers'),
    path('blogger/<int:pk>', views.AuthorDetail.as_view(), name='blog_author-detail'),
    path('blog/<int:pk>/create', views.BlogCommentCreate.as_view(), name='comment_create')
]
```

the template:

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <h1>Title: {{ blogauthor.title }}</h1>

  <p><strong>Author:</strong> <a href="">{{ blogauthor }}</a></p> 
  <p><strong>Biography:</strong> {{ blogauthor.biography }}</p> 
  <p><strong>User:</strong> {{ blogauthor.user }}</p>  
  <p><strong>Posts:</strong>    
  {% for blog in blogauthor.blogpost_set.all %}
      <p>  {{ blog.title }} </p>
  {% endfor %} </p>
  <form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
    {{ form.as_table }}
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>

  <div style="margin-left:20px;margin-top:20px">
    <h4>Comments: Coming Soon!</h4>
{% endblock %}
```

Model:

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    date_created = models.DateField(blank=False, default = date.today)
    blog_author = models.ForeignKey('BlogAuthor', on_delete = models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    title = models.TextField(max_length=70)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=400, null=False)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['date_created']
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """Returns the url to access a particular blog post instance."""
        return reverse('blogpost-detail', args=[str(self.id)])
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

And the forms.py:

```
class BlogSubmitForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField()
    content = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 40, 'rows': 8}))
    date_created = forms.DateField()
```

At this point, I suspect that the problem is related to my redirect() call in the form_valid override.

The things I have tried include:

1. Changing the form’s action from blank to the same URL as in my URL paths (possible I did this wrong)
2. Changing the code in form_valid() to read form.instance.blog_author = self.object (same exact error message, so I don’t think it’s this)
3. Fiddling with the form_valid()’s redirect call, including: using self.object instead or a URL, using a hardcoded url, getting rid of the second argument, and changing the 2nd arg to pk=, slug=.
4. Adding a get_success_url override (don’t really know why this would work)

edit: one of the excepted post calls that showed up in my local server went to blog/blogger/4, which is the url I want. Not sure what the issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is confusing on how you are using the template. Anyway, I think the simplest solution here is to get the `BlogAuthor` data from `request.user` and that is most logical, otherwise, anyone can post anything from another user as long as they can predict their primary key(which is a security hole). Here is how you can try:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class BlogSubmit(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = 'blogauthor_detail.html'
    form_class = BlogSubmitForm
    model = BlogPost

    def get_success_url(self):
      return reverse('blog_author-detail', pk=self.object.id)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.blog_author = self.request.user.blogauthor # assuming BlogAuthor has OneToOne relation with User
        return super(BlogSubmit, self).form_valid(form)
```

### Update

Purpose of FormView is to collect data from Forms, where CreateView is to store and create a new instance. Anyway, you need to change your code like this to make it work:

```
class BlogSubmit(LoginRequiredMixin, SingleObjectMixin, FormView):
    template_name = 'blogauthor_detail.html'
    form_class = BlogSubmitForm
    model = BlogAuthor

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('blog_author-detail', pk=self.object.id)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form.blog_author = self.object 
        form.save()
        return super(BlogSubmit, self).form_valid(form)
```

Also update the form:

```
class BlogSubmitForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
       model = BlogPost
       fields = ['title', 'date_created', 'content']
```

FYI, to make `SingleObjectMixin` work, you need to change the model from `BlogPost` to `BlogAuthor`

Comment: This worked 90%, just had to update the pk argument to a dict: kwargs={'pk': self.kwargs['pk'],

Comment: Oops, looks like the new blogposts aren't receiving an author from the detailview

Comment: I got this to work by changing the form_valid code back to how I had it in the original post.